# How do I get the first element of a HasMap using data bindings

Tags: angular

My problem is I have a HashMap, lets say

```
 prices = {{"one": "1"},{"two","2"}};
```

I want to be able to access the first element of this hashmap but inside of my html code, that is, using data bindings.

I tried:

```
 {{prices[Object.keys(prices)[0]]}}
```

but that does not work as you cannot use the Object notation inside the data bindings.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Is there perhaps any angular2 directive that could be used here? Any other approaches welcome as well.

Comment: shoudn't prices be an array? `[{"one": "1"},{"two": "2"}]`

Comment: yeah, that will be much easier, unfortunately that is not the case I'm dealing with

Comment: Unfortunately you can't tell which one is the first in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this by using a custom pipe that converts the map into an iterable as suggested [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2246#issuecomment-107212606). In particular I use the implementation provided [here](https://gist.github.com/amcdnl/202596c5b85cc66d7002d10bde3ab514).

with my directive looking now like this:

```
 {{(product.prices|iterable)[0].value.price}}
```